# Index Match Formula Shows Wrong Result

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I have two table, this one is the initial table that contains raw data (on Sheet 2)

[image: Raw Data]

And the second table (on Sheet 1) contains formula based on data from first table

[image: Result Data]

I use this formula to calculate the data, but as we can see on the picture, it doesn't produce right result. Could you please help me to modify the formula?

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$E$2:$E$12,MATCH(Sheet1!$B$1&Sheet1!B$2&Sheet1!$A3,Sheet2!$C$2:$C$12&Sheet2!$B$2:$B$12&Sheet2!$D$2:$D$12,0)),"")
```

Comment: I'd use an auxiliar column on the raw data joining the 3 keys to find a value: user, date and time. Then a simple `VLookUp` would do the trick

Comment: could you please show the example?

Comment: In `B3` put: `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$E:$E,MATCH(1,INDEX((Sheet2!$B$1:$B$12=B$2)*(Sheet2!$D$1:$D$12=$A3)*(Sheet2!$C$1:$C$12=$B$1),),0)),"")` and drag right and down...btw: merged cells are a pain in the ***, rather unmerge =)

Answer (score 0):

First the auxiliar column, using the concatenate operator `&` :

[image: Raw data]

Then the formula would be:

`=VLOOKUP(B$2&$E$1&$A3;Sheet2!$A:$G;6;0)`

Change 6 for 7 if you want the description instead of Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula. It should go into cell Sheet1!B3 where it must be confirmed with Ctl+Shift+Enter because it's an array formula. (017)

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX(Table,MATCH(1,(INDEX(Table,,3)=$A$1)*(INDEX(Table,,2)=B$2)*(INDEX(Table,,4)=$A3),0),5),"")
```

In preparation of this formula to work you need to set up a named range by the name of "Table" which comprises of Sheet2!A2:Fxx. Better set this range up dynamically so that it expands as you add more data but you can also declare it as Sheet2!A2:F1000 where 1000 is a number of rows you expect never to  need.

This table has 6 columns, A:F which I intentionally made to include column A, which you don't need so that range columns and sheet columns are identical. `Table,,3` simply defines the 3rd column. You can replace it with Sheet2!$C$2:$C$1000. If you do, make sure that all your ranges have identical sizes.

The 5 near the end of the formula, at `,0),5),"")` identifies the 5th column of the range `Table` from which the result is returned if the 3 criteria match. Change this number to 6 to return the result from column F or to 1 if you ever need the value from column A.